# Apache httpd web server Log Format required by STIG WG242 A22

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd, httpd.conf

I am currently trying to see whether our Apache Webserver (httpd) is compliant to [STIG Finding WG242 A22](https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/apache_site_2.2unix/2014-03-10/finding/V-13688).  This page has an example of LogFormat, as given below:

```
 LogFormat "%a %A %h %H %l %m %s %t %u %U \"%{Referer}i\" " combined
```

We are currently using,

```
 LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
```

Will it be violation of the STIG if the log format that is being used in our server did not match with the one present in [STIG page](https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/apache_site_2.2unix/2014-03-10/finding/V-13688).  Or is the STIG only saying that "you must have access log files, and the format can be anything of your liking".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the summary of the relevant [STIG requirements](https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/apache_site_2.2unix/2014-03-10/):

> **All directives specified in this STIG must be specifically set**

So no, it is  **not** sufficient to just log *"anything of your liking"*...

[V-13688](https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/apache_site_2.2unix/2014-03-10/finding/V-13688)  says:

> Items to be logged are as shown in this sample line in the httpd.conf file:
>
> `LogFormat "%a %A %h %H %l %m %s %t %u %U \"%{Referer}i\" " combined`
>
> *If the web server is not configured to capture the **required audit events*** for all sites and virtual directories, *this is a finding*.

With your current LogFormat settings as  they are you're not capturing **all required events** (you're not recording IP-addresses, omitting the required Referer header and missing still more) and that would be a finding.

> **Finding:**  V-13688
> **Severity:** Medium
> **Title:** Log file data must contain required data elements.
> **Description:**  The use of log files is a critical component of the operation of the Information Systems (IS) used within the DoD, and they can provide invaluable assistance with regard to damage assessment, ...

Arguably you are still free record the required audit events in a different order (the supplied LogFormat line is only a sample) and you're allowed to record [more request characteristics](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats). The required audit events only specify the *minimum detail* your logs should contain.   But before you  go wild there, the combined LogFormat is quite well supported by numerous tools and deviating from the conventional format might actually reduce the practical value of your logs in that regard.